# curl u = 0, u $\in H^1(\Omega, \mathbb{R}^n)$ => $ u \in C^\infty(\Omega ,\mathbb{R}^n)$

Tags: calculus

is the following statement true:
Let $u\in H^1(\Omega,\mathbb{R}^n)$ and curl u = 0 $\Rightarrow$ $u \in C^\infty(\Omega,\mathbb{R}^n)$,
in which curl u= 0 means: $\{\partial_i u^j - \partial_j u^i\}_{1\leq ij\leq n}=0$? 
If it isn't true:
-Does it become true, if also div u = 0?
-Is it possible to fix this statement, such that is becomes true?

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking about the [Poincare Lemma](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_and_exact_differential_forms)?

Comment: Yes. I would like to use this statement to prove the Poincare Lemma for sobolev-functions. I'm trying to understand the proof of Theorem 1 for m=0 in [link](http://perso.ensta-paristech.fr/~ciarlet/Resumes/07_CRASb.pdf) and would like to show the statement for the n-dimensional case.